# filter numpy array by another array of different shape

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

Given:

```
a = [[0, 1], [2, 2], [4, 2]]
b = [[0, 1, 2, 3], [2, 2, 3, 4], [4, 2, 3, 3], [2, 3, 3, 3]]
```

Solution is:

```
for (i,j) in zip(a[:, 0], a[:, 1]):
                print b[np.logical_and( a[:, 0] == i,  a[:, 1] == j)]
```

Result should be

```
[[0 1 2 3]]
[[2 2 3 4]]
[[4 2 3 3]]
```

Is there any solution for this problem without use of the `for`-loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given:

```
a = np.array(([0, 1], [2, 2], [4, 2]))
b = np.array(([0, 1, 2, 3], [2, 2, 3, 4], [4, 2, 3, 3], [2, 3, 3, 3]))
```

Calculate:

```
temp = np.in1d(b[:,0], a[:,0]) * np.in1d(b[:,1], a[:,1])
result = b[temp]
print 'result:', result
```

Output:

```
result: [[0 1 2 3]
 [2 2 3 4]
 [4 2 3 3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`NumPy broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html) for a vectorized solution, like so -

```
# 2D mask corresponding to all iterations of : 
# "np.logical_and( a[:, 0] == i,  a[:, 1] == j)"
mask = (a[:,None,0] == a[:,0]) & (a[:,None,1] == a[:,1])

# Use column indices of valid ones for indexing into b for final output
_,C_idx = np.where(mask)
out = b[C_idx]
```

Sample run -

```
In [67]: # Modified generic case
    ...: a = np.array([[0, 1], [3, 2], [3, 2]])
    ...: b = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 3], [2, 2, 3, 4], [4, 2, 3, 3], [2, 3, 3, 3]])
    ...: 
    ...: for (i,j) in zip(a[:, 0], a[:, 1]):
    ...:     print b[np.logical_and( a[:, 0] == i,  a[:, 1] == j)]
    ...:     
[[0 1 2 3]]
[[2 2 3 4]
 [4 2 3 3]]
[[2 2 3 4]
 [4 2 3 3]]

In [68]: mask = (a[:,None,0] == a[:,0]) & (a[:,None,1] == a[:,1])
    ...: _,C_idx = np.where(mask)
    ...: out = b[C_idx]
    ...: 

In [69]: out
Out[69]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [2, 2, 3, 4],
       [4, 2, 3, 3],
       [2, 2, 3, 4],
       [4, 2, 3, 3]])
```